# Finding critical points of functional (Euler equations)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Consider for $T>0$ the functional

$$u\mapsto J(u) := \int_0^T (\dot{u}(t)^2-u(t)^2)dt. $$

on the space $W_0^{1,\infty}((0,T),\mathbb{R})$.

(a) Depending on $T$, find the critical points of $J$

(b) Find the corresponding Jacobi-equations (Why are they the same for all critical points here?)

(c) For which values of $T$ can we can conclude that none of the critical points is a minimizer.

For (a) I thought using Euler equations to $F_u-\frac{d}{dt}F_p = -2u-2\ddot{u} =0.$
I would say that $u(t) = c_1\sin(x)+c_2\cos(x)$ are the only solutions, but i'm not sure of this. And in what way do these solutions depend on $T$?

For (b) the Jacobi equations are $\frac{d}{dt}F_{pp}\dot{\eta}+F_{pu}\eta =F_{pu}\dot{\eta}+F_{uu}\eta$. But then I get $2\ddot{\eta}=-2\eta$ which seems like the same equation but now for the unknown $\eta$...but I don't understand the question.

(c) Not sure how to go about this one..?

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read more carefully. For (a), note that we are working on the space $W_0^{1,\infty} ((0,T), \mathbf R)$, hence solutions have boundary values $u(0) = u(T) = 0$.

(Sorry for my short answer, but I seem not be able to add comments yet.)